# A system of linear recurrences

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am sorry if this is a very stupid question, but I am new in the topic and I was not able to find either a solution or relevant literature. (I am so new that I really don't know even what the right tags are!)

I have a system of two linear recurrences. In particular, the first recurrence is $x_n=998x_{n-1}+995y_{n-1}$; the second recurrence is $y_n=1000x_{n-1}+996y_{n-1}$. The initial conditions are $x_1=\frac{1993}{2}$ and $y_1=998$.

Can one write $x_n$ and $y_n$ in closed form?

More specifically, I am interested in understanding the limit of $\frac{x_n}{x_n+y_n}$. It sound like being very close to $\frac{1}{2}$. Related to this, does $\frac{x_n}{y_n}$ converges to 1?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Valerio

Comment: You could write it in matrix form.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.23

Comment: View $x_n$ and $y_n$ as components of a 2d vector $v_n$. Then $v_n=Av_{n-1}$ for a matrix $A$ which you can easily write down as an exercise, so you just need to compute the $n$-th power of $A$, as $v_n=A^nv_0$. Now, it's standard linear algebra. In fact, what I just said belongs to any good linear algebra course.

Comment: In particular, the correct tag is "linear algebra".

Comment: Once you write it in matrix form, you may be able to diagonalize it to a matrix D, so that  Av_n = D^nAv_0.  Anyway, if it is diagonalizable, you can linearly transform your recurrences to the form $u_n = d^nu_0$ and $v_n=c^nv_0$.  Good luck.  Gerhard "Gotta Go Change My Basis" Paseman, 2012.08.23

Comment: This really is not appropriate to MO, and in any case, @Vladmir answered the question in his comments, so voting to close.

Comment: You can also pull out the generating series x(t),y(t) by putting v(t)=[x(t),y(t)]^T and observing v(t)=tAv(t)+v(0). Then 
(I-tA)v(t)= v(0) and so $v(t)=det(I-tA)^{-1}Adj(I-tA)v(0)$. 

Comment: @Igor: I imagined it was really easy. I agree to close it ;) Thank you very much everyone for helping.

Comment: From what I wrote above you can use standard generating function techniques to find separate recurrences for x,y. 

Comment: Look in enumerative combnatorics by Stanley

Comment: @Vladimir: and even in some not-so-good linear algebra courses ;)

Comment: @Benjamin: Stanley's book is a bit of an overkill...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit of $x_n/(x_n+y_n)$ is not 1/2 but

$$331667 + 332\sqrt{995001}\over 663334 + 665\sqrt{995001}$$

The limit of $x_n/y_n$ is not 1 but

$$331667 + 332\sqrt{995001}\over 331667 + 333\sqrt{995001}$$

Comment: ahahha looks so nice! I am getting mad, without a computer program, to diagonalize $A$! 